# c++ error: vector subscript out of range, line 1201

Tags: c++, vector

New to c++. I'm getting the "out of range" error message when try to debug the code. I tried to used resize(), but it is still not fixed. The code is to read instructions into a 2d vector and print out the graph. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Pattern{
    int rowNum;
    int colNum;
    char token;
    bool isTriangular;
    bool isOuter;
}Pattern;

void CommandProcessing(vector<string>&, Pattern&);
void Builder(Pattern&, vector<vector<char>>&);
void Printer(vector<vector<char>>&);

int main()
{
    Pattern characters;
    vector<vector<char>> key;

    characters.colNum = 3;
    characters.rowNum = 3;
    characters.token = '@';
    characters.isOuter = false;
    characters.isTriangular = false;

    Builder(characters, key);
    Printer(key);
}

void Builder(Pattern& character, vector<vector<char>>& matrix)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char c;

    if (character.token == 0)
        c = 'a';
    else
        c = character.token;

    matrix.resize(character.rowNum);
    for (int i = 0; i < character.rowNum; i++){
        if (character.isTriangular)
            matrix[i].resize(i + 1);
        else
            matrix[i].resize(character.colNum);

        if (character.isOuter)
        {
            if (character.isTriangular)
            {
                if (i = j)
                    matrix[i][j] = c;
                else
                    matrix[character.rowNum - 1][i] = matrix[i][0] = c;
            }
            else
                matrix[0][j] = matrix[i][0] = matrix[character.rowNum - 1][j] = matrix[i][character.colNum - 1] = c;
            i++;
            j++;
        }

        else
        {
            if (character.isOuter)
            {
                while (i <= j){
                    for (i = 0; i < character.rowNum; i++)
                        for (j = 0; i < character.colNum; j++)
                            matrix[i][j] = c;
                }
            }
            else
                for (i = 0; i < character.rowNum; i++)
                    for (j = 0; i < character.colNum; j++)
                        matrix[i][j] = c;
        }
        c++;
    }

}
void Printer(vector<vector<char>>& print)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < print.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < print[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << print[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Giving the number of line in title without marking where it is in your posted code is useless (and fortunately, you don't post 1200+ lines)...

Comment: @Jarod42 I have no idea why it says line 1201, this is all the lines I have

Comment: It should be line in vector header... BTW, with debugger, you should know and highlight which line of your code has problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (i = j)` should be `if (i == j)`.

`if (i = j)` do a assignment and test if `i != 0`.

Other problems:

```
while (i <= j){
    for (i = 0; i < character.rowNum; i++)
        for (j = 0; i < character.colNum; j++) // You test `i` instead of j
            matrix[i][j] = c;
    // Once test fixed
    // Here `i == character.rowNum` and `j == character.colNum` (if `character.rowNum != 0`)
    // So the while loop condition doesn't change and may so do infinite loop
}
```

Comment: Was just about to post that the problem is in `for (j = 0; i < character.colNum; j++)` but you beat me to it :)

Comment: I've fixed the test, but I still don't understand  `if character.rowNum!=0` part

Comment: In short, I said that `while (i <= j)` should be removed (or logic inside should be changed).